# Phonegab build error ""

Tags: android, cordova

When I try to build an app in phonegab, I get this error:

```
* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.

>
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Rob\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: please remove platform android and add again then try for build...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, change the android SDK version in the AndroidManifest.xml (this file is in your android build map)

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

Change the SDK version to your current SDK version.
Hope this helps to other people :)